# Frequent errors on firestore: StructuredQuery.from cannot have more than one collection selector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, spring-webflux

I am running a Spring boot WebFlux application with reactive firestore repository. I am getting below exceptions in my logs quite frequently, it starts when I do a load test on application. However, with no load the application responds in normal way and no errors are seen in logs.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: StructuredQuery.from cannot have more than one collection selector.
```

I am not querying on multiple collections at the same time. Does anyone know what could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Can you show the query triggering the exception?

Comment: I am not writing query on my own, I am using spring cloud firestore with webflux, it facilitates JPA like repo declaration. So am using methods instead of queries such as 'findByName(String name)'

Comment: Please provide more information about the generated queries, which should be retrievable from the backend logs, as well as the database schema, data structure and methods you used in order to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some issue with double subscription which is now fixed. Please refer

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2548/files

Waiting for release.